# Convert SmallInt to Datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please help me to convert the following values to datetime:

```
DayLastAccessed
-23569
-23789
-23629
-23564
-23732
0
0
```

The above column is smallint type in SQL Server.

I'm using the following query to convert, but no luck:

```
select DayLastAccessed, cast(DayLastAccessed as datetime) from Webs
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, (1) why is this stored as a smallint in the first place, and (2) what "date" does -23569 represent?

Comment: Hey, aron, I tried the following query-----------------------
select DATEADD(d, DayLastAccessed + 65536, CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/1899', 101)) AS
lastAccessDate, DayLastAccessed from Webs ----------------
And I'm getting a proper date. So that's why I asked. Thanks for helping me on this

Comment: Using the calculation in your previous comment it sounds like for some (very very strange) reason the date was stored as number of days prior to '2078-06-07'.  At that point the following works `SELECT dateadd(d, LastDateAccessed, '2078-06-07') FROM tablename`

Comment: Hey Kenneth, still getting the same output. 2078-06-07

Comment: I don't see how this is doable unless you tell us what the `smallint` represent as @AaronBertrand suggested.

Answer (score 4):

A `smallint` data type uses the msb (most significant bit) to indicate the sign of the value.  The range of values, therefore, is -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767).

If the value is converted into an unsigned integer, these values look like the number of days since 1900-01-01 (the standard "epoch" value used by many Windows apps).

You can fairly easily convert the valid range of `smallint` values into dates using this:

```
DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(2), CONVERT(smallint, -23732), 0), 0))
```

So, for the values listed in your question, you get:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(2), CONVERT(smallint, -23569), 0), 0))
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(2), CONVERT(smallint, -23789), 0), 0))
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(2), CONVERT(smallint, -23629), 0), 0))
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(2), CONVERT(smallint, -23564), 0), 0))
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(2), CONVERT(smallint, -23732), 0), 0))
```

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║ 2014-11-26 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-04-20 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-09-27 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-12-01 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-06-16 00:00:00.000 ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

Having said that, it's pretty impossible to tell if these dates are accurate for your implementation.  Without some other context, it's impossible to say definitively.